# how to get the keys of similar values in an multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am working with a multidimensional array in PHP. I would like to detect the presence of similar values, then count the number of similar values and out put the results. For example, given the following array:

```
$products = 
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [price] => 100
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [price] => 101
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 10
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [price] => 102
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 16
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [price] => 103
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [price] => 108
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 6
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [price] => 107
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 4
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [price] => 109
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 5
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [price] => 105
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 2
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [price] => 104
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 5
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [price] => 106
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 2
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [price] => 111
                [product] => cloths
                [qty] => 1
            )

    )
```

how to approach this problem?

```
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $price = $product['price'];
    //now using this price how can i get all keys which are equal to this price
}
```

**EDIT**
i have tried with this but no use

```
echo $key = array_search(100, array_column($products, 'price'));
```

Comment: Searching multidimensional array for subarrays containing the same key/value? I'm sure this has been asked here before. Have you searched the site?

Comment: What do you mean by "equal"? Prices which are "+/- x" or with the exact same value?

Comment: @jeromegamez - i want  all keys which prices are exact equal

Answer (score 0):

**try below:**

```
$keys =  array_keys(array_filter($product, function($val) {return $val['price'] == 100; })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create an array containing prices as keys and product keys as values:

```
$prices = array();
foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
    $prices[$product['price']][] = $key;
}
```

Now, `$prices[105]` contains an array of all product keys with price = 105 (in the specific example, it's only one: `7`):

```
var_dump($prices[105]);
# array(1) {
#   [0]=>
#   int(7)
# }
```